# Using multiple different group_by variables (dplyr) to summarise a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe "my_data" which contains 6 columns:

```
group1.members  group2.members  group3.members  price    price.2   price.3
 1                 1               1             800      877      334
 1                 2               1             850      877      334
 2                 2               1             859      877      334
 3                 1               1             859      877      334
 3                 1               2             870      877      334
 2                 2               2             870      877      334
 2                 3               2             870      877      334
 1                 3               3             880      877      334
```

I would like to summarise by ROW, the "price" columns of my_data into several separate dataframes, using group_by on a different "group.member" column for each. It seems though, that group_by does not allow this?

This is what I had in mind:

```
my_data <- as.data.frame(data)
num_of_years <- c(1,2,3)
for(i in 1:length(num_of_years)){
   price_means <- my_data %>% group_by(my_data[i]) %>% 
   select(-value) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE))) %>% 
   ungroup
   assign(paste("PriceMeans",i,sep=""),price_means, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

In other words:

- for i=1, use group_by(group1.members)
- for i=2, use group_by(group2.members)
- for i=3, use group_by(group3.members)

EDIT: MY SOLUTION BELOW:

```
for(i in 1:length(my_groups)){ 
  # construct the group to select
  current.group <- my_groups[i] 
  current.group <- paste0("memb_", current.group) 
  # construct the groups to exclude
  groups.to.drop <- my_groups[-i] 
  groups.to.drop <- paste0("memb_", groups.to.drop) 

  # Get Means 
  Means <- data %>% group_by_(as.name(current.group)) %>%  
    select(- c(ID, get(groups.to.drop))) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) 
  Means <- Means[,-1:-(length(my_groups)-1)] 
  Means <- as.list(Means) 
  assign(x = paste0("Means_",i), 
         value = Means,  
         envir = parent.env(new.env()) 
}
```

Comment: you would need to use lazyeval method of writing your functions.

Comment: thanks! i looked at the documentation of lazyeval but did not understand how to implement this. could you provide a short example maybe?

Comment: This particular link explains how to the lazyeval is handled by the dplyr library [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html)

Comment: @Arun, seems like we both have the *exact* same handle. That could be confusing. Would you consider making changes to yours? I only ask because I've been active under this handle under the R-tag longer (= many associate this handle to me already) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am by no means a `dplyr` expert but this seems to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
for (i in 1:length(num_of_years)){
  var1 <- names(my_data)[[i]]
  var2 <- c(var1)

  price_means <- my_data %>% 
    select(eval(i), price, price.2, price.3) %>% 
    group_by_(var2) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE))) %>% 
    ungroup()

  assign(paste("PriceMeans",i,sep=""),price_means, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. In the end I used something quite similar (see my question edit above)